# Rails API: redirect_to doesn't render view (JSON) as when visiting the same endpoint. How do you correctly redirect in an API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, redirect, view, routes

I'm building a simple Rails API that fetches some files from another API and processes them to be consumed.

When I'm done processing the file and populating the DB through the `admin#seed` endpoint, I want to make a `redirect_to` the `Client`'s `Index` to display all clients that have just been processed.

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :clients, only: [ :index ]

      resources :clients, only: [:show] do
        resources :payment_transactions, only: [:index]
      end
     get "/admin/seed", to: "admin#seed", as: :seed
     get "/admin/reset", to: "admin#reset", as: :reset
    end
  end
end
```

I'm redirecting to the `Client`'s `Index` after the `admin#seed` action is completed but instead of getting all instances of `Client` displayed (as when I visit that endpoint), I get nothing back.

I've tried a `redirect_to api_v1_clients_path` which gives the following server log:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/api/v1/clients
```

and `head :found, location: api_v1_clients_path` which produces the following server log:

```
Completed 302 Found in 171745ms (ActiveRecord: 1121.6ms | Allocations: 3056524)
```

..but still *nothing* shows up.

*Controller*

```
  def seed
    @builder = PaymentBuilder.new
    if @builder.process_file
      head :found, location: api_v1_clients_path(format: :json)
    end
  end
```

I'm making sure I specify the format with `(format: :json)` either way.

The endpoint works just fine if I visit it as a separate request.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to rails doc: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head , `head` returns a response that has no content. Consider using `render` with `status` option or `redirect_to` instead.

Answer (score 0):

30x was base on Location in headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location

rails http code: https://gist.github.com/mlanett/a31c340b132ddefa9cca

```
render json: { xxx: 'xxx' }, status: :found, location: xxx_path
```